# Grails Fixture plugin keeps saying build-test-data plugin is not installed

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have the following dependency declaration in `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
plugins {
    test ':build-test-data:2.2.1'
    test ':fixtures:1.3'
}
```

I've already run `refresh-dependencies` on both the terminal, and my IDE (Eclipse) but every time I run the test I get:

```
grails.plugin.fixtures.exception.FixtureException: build feature is unavailable as build-test-data plugin is not installed
    at grails.plugin.fixtures.builder.FixtureBuilder.assertBuildTestDataPluginInstalledIfNeeded(FixtureBuilder.groovy:135)
    at grails.plugin.fixtures.builder.FixtureBuilder.beans(FixtureBuilder.groovy:104)
    at grails.plugin.fixtures.builder.FixtureBuilder.build(FixtureBuilder.groovy:82)
    at grails.plugin.fixtures.Fixture.build(Fixture.groovy:48)
    at grails.plugin.fixtures.FixtureLoader.build(FixtureLoader.groovy:54)
```

I checked the [`FixtureBuilder` code](https://github.com/gpc/grails-fixtures/blob/master/src/groovy/grails/plugin/fixtures/builder/FixtureBuilder.groovy#L49), and found the following line:

```
Holders.pluginManager.hasGrailsPlugin('build-test-data')
```

I created a separate test to check what this line returns, but no matter what plugin (declared in `BuildConfig.groovy`) I replace `'build-test-data'` with, it always returns `false`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I guess you already tried to type `grails clean-all` ?

Comment: What does it do? I even tried creating a new Grails project to check if it works, but I got the same thing.

Comment: a quick try would be to comment those lines out, `run-app` then uncomment and `run-app again

Answer (score 0):

In `BuildConfig` there are four possible options to configure a plugin:

- build
- compile
- runtime
- test

`Fixture` and `Build` plugins are configured to be use in `test` you should to change it to `runtime` to use them in `BootStrap` when running the app.

Comment: Right now, I don't mean to use the plugin elsewhere but in the tests, but even after changing the scope to `runtime` I still get the same error.

Comment: runtime ":build-test-data:2.2.1" / / / runtime ":fixtures:1.3.1-SNAPSHOT"  What grails version are you running?

Comment: SNAPSHOT of fixtures plugin still doesn't work. I'm using Grails 2.4.3.