# Fixtures plugin throws BeanCreationException on load

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm trying to get the Fixtures plugin working for my unit tests but every time I make it load data, I always get a `BeanCreationException`.

Here's how the `setup` method in my Spec looks like:

```
def fixtureLoader = new FixtureLoader(grailsApplication)

def setup() {
    fixtureLoader.load {
        person(Person, firstName: 'Juan', lastName: 'dela Cruz')
    }
}
```

Every time I run any test I get:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'person': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getDomainClass() on null object
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.getApplicationContext(DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.java:156)
    at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.createApplicationContext(BeanBuilder.java:593)
    at grails.plugin.fixtures.builder.FixtureBuilder.createApplicationContext(FixtureBuilder.groovy:140)
    at grails.plugin.fixtures.Fixture.load(Fixture.groovy:43)
    at grails.plugin.fixtures.FixtureLoader.load(FixtureLoader.groovy:50)
    at demo.SampleSpec.setup(SampleSpec.groovy:16)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getDomainClass() on null object
    at grails.plugin.fixtures.builder.processor.FixtureBeanPostProcessor.getDomainClass(FixtureBeanPostProcessor.groovy:136)
    at grails.plugin.fixtures.builder.processor.FixtureBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(FixtureBeanPostProcessor.groovy:40)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:421)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1558)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: if you fixed it, please share the solution with me!

Comment: Have you checked if grailsApplication is injected? if not try `Holders.grailsApplication`

Comment: Hey, sorry I can't remember how I got around this, but, yeah I think it had to do with `grailsApplication`. However, after solving this one, I got another [problem that I still don't know how to fix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112132/grails-fixture-plugin-keeps-saying-build-test-data-plugin-is-not-installed).