# What are the approaches for special domain objects?

Tags: oop, grails

(This is a bit of a general question but I'm tagging it with Grails since that's what I'm using to build the application.)

There are business (or maybe technical) requirements that force you to assume particular instances of a Domain Class exist (persistent) from the moment your application is deployed. For example, the system requires an administrative/super User to exist from the start. Another example is that when you keep track of all Client applications to your application (server), and your application acts a special client for itself. In addition, there may be rules around these instances that probably won't apply to others of the same type. What's the object-oriented approach to this? In particular, are there built-in features of Grails that support this? There maybe different approaches to different specific situations, but I'd like to know what the widely accepted practices are for this type of problems.

Answer (score 1):

I use the Grails BootStrap.groovy file during init if the special instances are not already there I will create them. I will also set flags in config that will control how much data I will bootstrap. Having the ability of a new dev to have all needed data and some samples all loaded into the app is very helpful.

The special case is anything with logins for production. In that case I don't bootstrap those directly but will build that data into the setup for production I don't want to keep the same log in details for dev/qa/etc and production super user. And many times super user just isn't in production but users with that role.

Comment: Yeah, `BootStrap` seems to be the most intuitive choice. However, my concern does not end with data existing upon start up. Another thing is that I want to be able to identify those special domain instances without relying too much on fields that can change (most of them are). The most reliable identifier is, I think the primary key, but I'm not sure if I should keep track of those for every special instance.

Comment: If they are very special domain instances you could strongly type instead of having your super user be an instance of user make SuperUser extend User and only have one instance of that. I personally wouldn't do that for the user case I would just have a super user role never know when you will need that with more than one log in but it may work in your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can to use the `BootStrap.groovy` file as @jeffbeck suggest to you. That is the option for beginning of times in grails. You can combine this with the [`fixture plugin`](http://grails.org/plugin/fixtures) which allow you to create a complex structure of data in groovy scripts. You can to use conditional in `BootStrap.groovy` to be very specific on what fixtures load.

```
import grails.util.Environment
import grails.plugin.fixtures.FixtureLoader

class BootStrap {
    FixtureLoader fixtureLoader

    def init = { servletContext ->
        Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment {
            development {
                fixtureLoader.load('developmentFixtures')
            }
            production {
                fixtureLoader.load('productionFixtures')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are other options like to use the [`Database Migration Plugin`](http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration) But we never try this.

Comment: I use the Database Migration Plugin and it can work for what you want but it works best if it's the same data everywhere and I find it easier to do complex work in the BootStrap

Comment: Is hard to know what is happening. There are error messages? Logs? Can you post the fixtures?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112132/grails-fixture-plugin-keeps-saying-build-test-data-plugin-is-not-installed